# Solid turn signal (one side)

Tags: lights, indicators

My car just suddenly has two solid indicator lights that are staying solid - only on one side (mirror and rear).

They do blink when signalling but stay lit and just dull rather than turn off mid indication.

When the car is locked, the lights do eventually go off but just go solid and stay solid whilst unlocked and in motion. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model of the car in question?